# Show database in mongodb show it empty while I can acess and query data

Tags: mongodb, show, pymongo

While accessing the database in command line,
the 'show dbs' list all the existing databases showing the one I want to access **as empty**.

**EDIT:**  Neverless using the database and running db.stats() it show the correct size of data.

The output of show dbs :

> db1    (empty)
>
> db2    (empty)
>
> db3    0.999755859375GB
>
> db_5   (empty)

But I can access, query, count and show the data stored in db_5.

Can someone explain me why this is shown as empty?
Can I export it correctly without loosing data?

**EDIT**:
After export and then stopping and restarting mongodb: database is now shown as completly empty and I'm then unable to select count or show data.

Comment: What is the output of `db.stats()` in `db_5` and `db.adminCommand("listDatabases");`?

Comment: db.admin.Command for db_5 {
   "name" : "db_5",
   "sizeOnDisk" : 1,
   "empty" : false
  }, db.stats is goind well {
 "db" : "db_5",
 "collections" : 7,
 "objects" : 476471,
 "avgObjSize" : 686.5640595125411,
 "dataSize" : 327127864,
 "storageSize" : 393261056,
 "numExtents" : 34,
 "indexes" : 5,
 "indexSize" : 15542576,
 "fileSize" : 0,
 "nsSizeMB" : 16,
 "dataFileVersion" : {
  "major" : 4,
  "minor" : 5
 },
 "ok" : 1
}

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you have to update your MongoDB Shell.

> There's a known issue ([SERVER-15987](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-15987)) where listCollections
>   returns empty when an old version of the shell is used.

When executing the `mongo` command, you can see the shell version in the first line.

`MongoDB shell version: 3.0.4`

If you have anything less than `3.0`, you should update your shell.
In Debian, this can be reinstalled using `apt-get install mongodb-org-shell`

[source](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-16361)

Comment: I never reproduced this problem with upper version. Thx anyway!

Answer (score 10):

In my case I was accessing mongo without credentials.
So changed my command to

```
mongo --username mongouser --password mongopass
```

Comment: This worked like a charm, before I was typing `mongo` without the credentials and nothing showed up.