# mongo: Why I can't see collections?

Tags: mongodb

I used mongo shell and i can't see my collection even if it exists:

```
> db.first.insert({name:'test',value:10})
> db.first.insert({name:'test2',value:20})

> db.first.find()
{ "_id" : ObjectId("588122a970e3439f3e3964ad"), "name" : "test", "value" : 10 }
{ "_id" : ObjectId("588122b170e3439f3e3964ae"), "name" : "test2", "value" : 20 }
> show collections  
########## Here is no results !!!! ############
> db.first.drop()  
true
> db.first.drop()
false
```

Any suggestions ?

Regards, Olaf

mongod --version

db version v3.4.1

build environment:
    distmod: debian81
    distarch: x86_64
    target_arch: x86_64

Comment: you have tried db.getCollectionNames() ?  What mongo shell version are you using?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Show database in mongodb show it empty while I can acess and query data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19553554/show-database-in-mongodb-show-it-empty-while-i-can-acess-and-query-data)

Comment: What is the output of `version()` in your `mongo` shell?

Comment: I cannot see the collections in mongo shell 4.0.24 from mongoserver 4.0.24 atlas AWS. I have no admin access.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

#

The answer but not the explanation:

I used mogodb in docker , the version of the docker mogngo was newer then the client version on host.

When i attached to the contener and used the same client and server version everything works fine

Thanks

Comment: You didn't provide the specific `version()` reported by the `mongo` shell, but given the problem description I'm guessing it was 2.6 or older. MongoDB 3.0 added a storage engine API which older shells and drivers will not be aware of. In particular, outdated driver versions will not fully support for the WiredTiger storage engine or the default SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication. See: [Driver Compatibility Changes](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.0-compatibility/#driver-compatibility-changes).

Comment: mongod --version -> db version v3.4.1

    MongoDB shell version: 2.4.10